# pyspark join dataframes on each word and compare list with string

Tags: pyspark

I am using pyspark and I have 2 tables :

- table REF_A

```
id | name
---------
1  | help
2  | need
3  | hello
4  | hel
```

- Table DATA_B contains a list

```
| sentence                  |
----------------------------
| [I , say , hello, to, you]|
| [I , need , your, help]   |
```

I need to join the 2 tables in a way to have this result:

```
id | name  | sentence          |
---------------------------------
1  | help  | I need your help
2  | need  | I need your help  |
3  | hello | I say hello to you|
```

because in REF_A i have the KEY WORD "need" i need to match it with the sentence containing "need", which is "I need your help"

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

```
REF_A.createOrReplaceTempView('REF_A')
DATA_B.createOrReplaceTempView('DATA_B')
spark.sql('SELECT * FROM REF_A LEFT JOIN DATA_B ON ARRAY_CONTAINS(DATA_B.sentence, REF_A.name);')
```